# Javascript code has far too many if statements, I need an alternative

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    const app = (() => {


  let race1 = document.querySelector('.race1');
  let race2 = document.querySelector('.race2');
  let race3 = document.querySelector('.race3');
  let race4 = document.querySelector('.race4');
  let race5 = document.querySelector('.race5');
  let race6 = document.querySelector('.race6');



  const returnAll = () => {
    fetch('php/index.php')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((myJson) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
          if (myJson[i].race1 == 1) {race1.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
          if (myJson[i].race2 == 1) {race2.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
          if (myJson[i].race3 == 1) {race3.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
          if (myJson[i].race4 == 1) {race4.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
          if (myJson[i].race5 == 1) {race5.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
          if (myJson[i].race6 == 1) {race6.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}

        }

      });

    console.log(allEnteries)

  }

  return {

    init: () => {

      returnAll();
    }


  }



})();


app.init();
```

All the information above is correct and works occordingly. I just need a better way to code this rather than  multiple if statements, Switch would pretty mucch be the same!
Any suggestions? I find multple If statements are easy to read, however I've been told this is bad coding

Comment: This is more suited for the Code Review Stack Exchange. That said: the only thing changing anywhere is a single digit--seems straight-forward.

Comment: Hint: ``Object.keys(myJson[i]).forEach(k => document.querySelector(`.${k}`).innerHTML ...)``…

Comment: Thanks @deceze  I like your theory. my only issue is this 

if(myJson[i].race[i] == 1)
I can't do the initial compare! I need to compare myJson.race1 = 1 myJson.race2 =1 and so on? Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Put them on an array:

```
let races =[];
races.push(document.querySelector('.race1'));
races.push(document.querySelector('.race2'));
...
races.push(document.querySelector('.race6'));
...
 for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
          if (myJson[i].races[i] == 1) {races[i].innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the initial redundancy, and assumes a specific length--while it *may* be true that races and myJson share indices, it's not a given.

Comment: Yep, there's a typo in this answer*(two nested loops are needed, one over `myJson`, the other over `races`),* but the notion is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Define the number of races as a variable, and use it to generate the dynamic variable variables you need:

```
const app = (() => {

  let numRaces = 6,
      raceElements = [ ];

  for( var i = 0; i < numRaces; i++ )
  {
    raceElements.push( document.querySelector('.race'+(i+1)) );
  }

  const returnAll = () => {
    fetch('php/index.php').then((response) => { return response.json(); }).then((myJson) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {

        for( var r = 0; r < numRaces; r++ )
        {
          if( myJson[i]['race'+(r + 1)])
          {
            raceElements[r].innerHTML+= '<div>'+myJson[i].email+'</div>';
          }
        }
      }
    });

    console.log(allEnteries);
  }

  return {
    init: () => {
      returnAll();
    }
  }
})();

app.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

With functionnal programming:

```js
const races = Array(6).fill().map((_, k) => document.querySelector(`.race${k + 1}`));

const returnAll = () => {
    fetch('php/index.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => races.forEach((race, i) => {
            if (json[i][`race${i+1}`] === 1) {
                race.innerHTML += `<div>${json[i].email} </div>`;
            }
        }));
};
```